# Using '#' and '##' preprocessing operators together

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

From what I have read I understand that `#` operator is used with a parametric macro to convert it's parameter to a string and `##` is used to join two parameters or a parameter with some other identifier (Correct me if my understanding is wrong).

But how can I use both `#` and `##` operator together? I tried it by doing:

```
#define str(n)  #n ## #n
```

I thought then

```
printf("%s",str(Hello))
```

will be expanded as

```
printf("%s", "Hello""Hello")
```

And as adjacent strings are joined automatically to make one string in C so, this will lead to  `printf("%s", "HelloHello")` and output will be`HelloHello`. But the story was different, it throws an error:

> pasting "hello" and "hello" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Please explain me how these parametric macros with `#` and `##` operator are expanded.

Comment: What error does it "throw"?

Comment: **Error :** pasting "hello" and "hello" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Answer (score 3):

`##` "joining two parameters" is a vast oversimplification. This operator joins **tokens**. And the result must be a single *valid* token. Two string literal tokens cannot be token pasted into a single token.

Furthermore, string literal concatenation is handled at a later translation phase. So an obvious fix to your macro is to not use `##` at all.

```
#define str(n) #n #n
```

But if you really want to use both, then you need to token paste *before* stringifying. And do that via an intermediate macro expansion.

```
#define str(n) str_(n ## n)
#define str_(nn) #nn
```